# how to avoid using _siftup or _siftdown in heapq

Tags: python, heap

I have no idea how to solve following problem efficiently without using `_siftup` or `_siftdown`:

How to restore the heap invariant, when one element is out-of-order?

In other words, update `old_value` in `heap` to `new_value`, and keep `heap` working. you can assume there is only one `old_value` in heap. The fucntion definition is like:

```
def update_value_in_heap(heap, old_value, new_value):
```

Here is my real scenario, read it if you are interested in.

- You can imagine it is a small autocomplete system. I need to count
  the frequency of words, and maintain the top k max-count words, which
  prepare to output at any moment. So I use `heap` here. When one word
  count++, I need update it if it is in heap.
- All the words and counts are stored in trie-tree's leaf, and heaps
  are stored in trie-tree's middle nodes. If you care about the word
  out of heap, don't worry, I can get it from trie-tree's leaf node.
- when user type a word, it will first read from heap and then update
  it. For better performance, we can consider decrease update frequency
  by updated in batch.

So how to update the heap, when one particular word count increase?

Here is _siftup or _siftdown version simple example(not my scenario):

```
>>> from heapq import _siftup, _siftdown, heapify, heappop

>>> data = [10, 5, 18, 2, 37, 3, 8, 7, 19, 1]
>>> heapify(data)
>>> old, new = 8, 22              # increase the 8 to 22
>>> i = data.index(old)
>>> data[i] = new
>>> _siftup(data, i)
>>> [heappop(data) for i in range(len(data))]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 18, 19, 22, 37]

>>> data = [10, 5, 18, 2, 37, 3, 8, 7, 19, 1]
>>> heapify(data)
>>> old, new = 8, 4              # decrease the 8 to 4
>>> i = data.index(old)
>>> data[i] = new
>>> _siftdown(data, 0, i)
>>> [heappop(data) for i in range(len(data))]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 18, 19, 37]
```

it costs O(n) to index and O(logn) to update. `heapify` is another solution, but 
less efficient than `_siftup` or `_siftdown`.

But `_siftup` and `_siftdown` are protected member in heapq, so they are not recommended to access from outside.

So is there a better and more efficient way to solve this problem? Best practice for this situation?

Thanks for reading, I really appreciate it to help me out. : )

already refer to [heapq python - how to modify values for which heap is sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674161/heapq-python-how-to-modify-values-for-which-heap-is-sorted), but no answer to my problem

Comment: You don't need to use heapq for heap operations. You can write them yourself.

Comment: (This is a pretty inefficient way to do update operations, by the way - usually, if you need that kind of operation, you'd keep an auxiliary mapping or something else to record where each heap entry is.)

Comment: Yes, we can, and it seems not a complex problem. But I think I prefer to reusing code and focusing on my own logic. @user2357112

Comment: heapq doesn't provide the operations you're looking for, unless you count private helpers as "provided". The point of this task is likely to *make* you write heap operations yourself.

Comment: actually I means other solution to avoid _siftup or _siftdown, not one single lib function to implement my requirement. : ) @user2357112

Comment: Why doesn't the "Invalidate and Reinsert" approach address your question? Seems like it does: mark the old_value as removed and add it back as the new_value with the revised priority.

Comment: `"mark the old_value as removed"` how to pop old_value out in a heap?If you remove it as list way, it is less efficient than edit and `heapify`. It seems edit node directly and sift is the most efficient way. @gregory

Comment: @recnac You're not removing the old_value, rather you are marking it something to be ignored. Then, when popping from the heap, you filter out those invalidated entries.

Comment: @gregory: You'd need a bunch of extra adapter code to get around the fact that heapq doesn't have a concept of dummy entries, and unless you keep track of dummy count and rebuild the heap when it gets too high, you risk growing the heap indefinitely with dummy entries. Overall, it's simpler to just implement siftup/siftdown yourself. Really, siftup/siftdown is a lot simpler to implement than the stuff you'd need to write to avoid it.

Comment: I totally agree with you. So in my knowledge bound, sift is the best way @user2357112

Comment: @user2357112 the question was "how to avoid using" siftup and siftdown. In light of that, my suggestion was to use a well-documented approach to address this need. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes. IMO, this doesn't seem like" a lot" adapter code. That said,  yes, the dummy entries is a down-side to this approach.

Comment: Raymond Hettinger has been very thorough in his description, and is very well versed in how heaps work and how the Python `heapq` library works. If you are going to follow his *Direct Heap Adjustment* pattern, then *no*, there is no way to re-implement that approach with anything other than the internal `_siftdown` and `_siftup` options. Have you considered asking him in a comment on his answer, though?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, what is supposed to happen if you have two `8` in your first example? Should you replace both of them, or an arbitrary occurence of `8`, or do you suppose that someone messed up with your heap and you only want to restore it to a coherent state? You should probably describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: two `8` explains use `_siftup` when increase and `_siftdown` when decrease. like you said, I want to restore the heap in coherent state after one element need to be changed. For example, heap store the count of objs, one obj `count+=1`, and I want to update the heap @cglacet

Comment: I'm still not sure to get it, who is calling `data[i] = new`, ie., is it supposed to be a normal use of your object? If it is, then why is it? If it's not then just prevent accessing `__setitem__` on your heap. To me `data[i] = new` looks like an attack on your heap. If you really need to deal with this, then sorting your heap every time someone is attacking it seems perfectly fine to me. You could even do this in a lazier fashion, resorting only if someone is using normal heap methods. In any case your attacker code `data.index(old)` is so slow that any strategy will do.

Comment: Here is my scenario, I need to count the frequency of words, and maintain the top k max-count words, which prepare to output at any moment. When one word count++, I need update it if it is in heap. If you care about the word out of heap, don't worry, I can get it from trie-tree's leaf node (store all word and count). @cglacet

Comment: Ok. And how often do you think you'll be reading (preparing output) compared to writing (counting)?

Comment: You can imagine it is a small autocomplete system. when type in, it will first reading and then writing. Almost 1:1, but, for better performance, we can consider decrease update frequency by updated in batch. Thanks for your help : ) @cglacet

Comment: I think you should update your question with these additional pieces of information as it may really help people giving you better advices. I'll try to have a look at the performances of the different methods.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have added my real scenario in question. If you get a answer, please write it in answer, I can bounty to you. @cglacet

Comment: If you need to investigate other options (if you need something faster than this) you can still open a question describing your problem and you current solution. I really think a better data structure can be found for your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `heapify`.

One important thing that you have to keep in mind is that theoretical complexity and performances are two different things (even though they are related). In other words, implementation does matter too. Asymptotic complexities give you some *lower bounds* that you can see as guarantees, for example an algorithm in O(n) ensure that in the worst case scenario, you will execute a number of instructions that is linear in the input size. There are two important things here:

1. constants are ignored, but constants matter in real life;
2. the worst case scenario is dependent on the algorithm you consider, not only on the input.

Depending on the topic/problem you consider, the first point can be very important. In some domains, constants hidden in asymptotic complexities are so big that you can't even build inputs that are bigger than the constants (or that input wouldn't be realistic to consider). That's not the case here, but that's something you always have to keep in mind.

Giving these two observations, you can't really say: *implementation B is faster than A because A is derived from a O(n) algorithm and B is derived from a O(log n) algorithm*. Even if that's a good argument to start with in general, it's not always sufficient. Theoretical complexities are especially good for comparing algorithms when all inputs are equally likely to happen. In other words, when you algorithms are very generic.

In the case where you know what your use cases and inputs will be you can just test for performances directly. Using both the tests and the asymptotic complexity will give you a good idea on how your algorithm will perform (in both extreme cases and arbitrary practical cases).

That being said, lets run some performance tests on the following class that will implement [three different strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674361/1720199) (there are actually four strategies here, but *Invalidate and Reinsert* doesn't seem right in your case as you'll invalidate each item as many time as you see a given word). I'll include most of my code so you can double check that I haven't messed up (you can even check the [complete notebook](https://github.com/cglacet/Blog/blob/master/python/heap_invariant_attack.ipynb)):

```py
from heapq import _siftup, _siftdown, heapify, heappop

class Heap(list):
  def __init__(self, values, sort=False, heap=False):
    super().__init__(values)
    heapify(self)
    self._broken = False
    self.sort = sort
    self.heap = heap or not sort

  # Solution 1) repair using the knowledge we have after every update:        
  def update(self, key, value):
    old, self[key] = self[key], value
    if value > old:
        _siftup(self, key)
    else:
        _siftdown(self, 0, key)
    
  # Solution 2 and 3) repair using sort/heapify in a lazzy way:
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value)
    self._broken = True
    
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if self._broken:
        self._repair()
        self._broken = False
    return super().__getitem__(key)

  def _repair(self):  
    if self.sort:
        self.sort()
    elif self.heap:
        heapify(self)

  # … you'll also need to delegate all other heap functions, for example:
  def pop(self):
    self._repair()
    return heappop(self)
```

We can first check that all three methods work:

```py
data = [10, 5, 18, 2, 37, 3, 8, 7, 19, 1]

heap = Heap(data[:])
heap.update(8, 22)
heap.update(7, 4)
print(heap)

heap = Heap(data[:], sort_fix=True)
heap[8] = 22
heap[7] = 4
print(heap)

heap = Heap(data[:], heap_fix=True)
heap[8] = 22
heap[7] = 4
print(heap)
```

Then we can run some performance tests using the following functions:

```py
import time
import random

def rand_update(heap, lazzy_fix=False, **kwargs):
    index = random.randint(0, len(heap)-1)
    new_value = random.randint(max_int+1, max_int*2)
    if lazzy_fix:
        heap[index] = new_value
    else:
        heap.update(index, new_value)
    
def rand_updates(n, heap, lazzy_fix=False, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(n):
        rand_update(heap, lazzy_fix)
        
def run_perf_test(n, data, **kwargs):
    test_heap = Heap(data[:], **kwargs)
    t0 = time.time()
    rand_updates(n, test_heap, **kwargs)
    test_heap[0]
    return (time.time() - t0)*1e3

results = []
max_int = 500
nb_updates = 1

for i in range(3, 7):
    test_size = 10**i
    test_data = [random.randint(0, max_int) for _ in range(test_size)]

    perf = run_perf_test(nb_updates, test_data)
    results.append((test_size, "update", perf))
    
    perf = run_perf_test(nb_updates, test_data, lazzy_fix=True, heap_fix=True)
    results.append((test_size, "heapify", perf))

    perf = run_perf_test(nb_updates, test_data, lazzy_fix=True, sort_fix=True)
    results.append((test_size, "sort", perf))
```

The results are the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dtf = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["heap size", "method", "duration (ms)"])
print(dtf)

sns.lineplot(
    data=dtf, 
    x="heap size", 
    y="duration (ms)", 
    hue="method",
)
```

[image]

From these tests we can see that `heapify` seems like the most reasonable choice, it has a decent complexity in the worst case: O(n) and perform better in practice. On the other hand, it's probably a good idea to investigate other options (like having a data structure dedicated to that particular problem, for example using bins to drop words into, then moving them from a bin to the next look like a possible track to investigate).

Important remark: this scenario (updating vs. reading ratio of 1:1) is unfavorable to both the `heapify` and `sort` solutions. So if you manage to have a k:1 ratio, this conclusion will be even clearer (you can replace `nb_updates = 1` with `nb_updates = k` in the above code).

Dataframe details:

```
    heap size   method  duration in ms
0        1000   update        0.435114
1        1000  heapify        0.073195
2        1000     sort        0.101089
3       10000   update        1.668930
4       10000  heapify        0.480175
5       10000     sort        1.151085
6      100000   update       13.194084
7      100000  heapify        4.875898
8      100000     sort       11.922121
9     1000000   update      153.587103
10    1000000  heapify       51.237106
11    1000000     sort      145.306110
```

Comment: Here is the kicker: `heapify` uses n/2 number of `_siftup` (I'm looking straight at the source code of heapify). So how would one `_siftup` be so much slower than n/2 of them? Something is wrong with this man.

Comment: Looks like Tojik remeasured

Answer (score 9):

The answer from @cglacet is completely wrong, but looks very legit.
The code snippet he provided is completely broken! It is also very hard to read.
`_siftup()` is called n//2 times in `heapify()` so it cannot be faster than `_siftup()` by itself.

To answer the original question, there is no better way. If you are concerned about the methods being private, create your own that do the same thing.

The only thing I agree with is, that if you don't need to read from the heap for a long time, it **might** be beneficial to lazy `heapify()` it once you need them. The question is if you should use a heap for that then.

Let's go over the problems with his snippet:

The `heapify()` function gets called multiple times for the "update" run.
The chain of errors that lead to this is as follows:

- He passes `heap_fix`, but expects `heap` and the same is true for `sort`
- If `self.sort` is always `False`, the `self.heap` is always `True`
- He redefines `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` which are called every time `_siftup()` of `_siftdown()` assign or read something (note: these two aren't called in C, so they use `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()`)
- If `self.heap` is `True` and `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` are being called, the `_repair()` function is called every time `_siftup()` or `siftdown()` swap elements. But the call to `heapify()` is done in C, so `__getitem__()` does not get called, and it doesn't end up in an infinite loop
- He redefines `self.sort` so calling it, like he tries to do, would fail
- He reads once, but updates an item `nb_updates` times, not 1:1 like he claims

I fixed the example, I tried verifying it as best as I could, but we all make mistakes. Feel free to check it yourself.

### Code

```
import time
import random

from heapq import _siftup, _siftdown, heapify, heappop

class UpdateHeap(list):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super().__init__(values)
        heapify(self)

    def update(self, index, value):
        old, self[index] = self[index], value
        if value > old:
            _siftup(self, index)
        else:
            _siftdown(self, 0, index)

    def pop(self):
        return heappop(self)

class SlowHeap(list):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super().__init__(values)
        heapify(self)
        self._broken = False
        
    # Solution 2 and 3) repair using sort/heapify in a lazy way:
    def update(self, index, value):
        super().__setitem__(index, value)
        self._broken = True
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self._broken:
            self._repair()
            self._broken = False
        return super().__getitem__(index)

    def _repair(self):
        ...

    def pop(self):
        if self._broken:
            self._repair()
        return heappop(self)

class HeapifyHeap(SlowHeap):

    def _repair(self):
        heapify(self)


class SortHeap(SlowHeap):

    def _repair(self):
        self.sort()

def rand_update(heap):
    index = random.randint(0, len(heap)-1)
    new_value = random.randint(max_int+1, max_int*2)
    heap.update(index, new_value)
    
def rand_updates(update_count, heap):
    for i in range(update_count):
        rand_update(heap)
        heap[0]
        
def verify(heap):
    last = None
    while heap:
        item = heap.pop()
        if last is not None and item < last:
            raise RuntimeError(f"{item} was smaller than last {last}")
        last = item

def run_perf_test(update_count, data, heap_class):
    test_heap = heap_class(data)
    t0 = time.time()
    rand_updates(update_count, test_heap)
    perf = (time.time() - t0)*1e3
    verify(test_heap)
    return perf


results = []
max_int = 500
update_count = 100

for i in range(2, 7):
    test_size = 10**i
    test_data = [random.randint(0, max_int) for _ in range(test_size)]

    perf = run_perf_test(update_count, test_data, UpdateHeap)
    results.append((test_size, "update", perf))
    
    perf = run_perf_test(update_count, test_data, HeapifyHeap)
    results.append((test_size, "heapify", perf))

    perf = run_perf_test(update_count, test_data, SortHeap)
    results.append((test_size, "sort", perf))

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dtf = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["heap size", "method", "duration (ms)"])
print(dtf)

sns.lineplot(
    data=dtf, 
    x="heap size", 
    y="duration (ms)", 
    hue="method",
)
```

### Results

As you can see, the "update" method using `_siftdown()` and `_siftup()` is asymptotically faster.

You should know what your code does, and how long will it take to run. If in doubt you shouůd check. @cglaced checked how long does the execution take, but he didn't question how long should it take. If he did, he would find the two don't match up. And others fell for it.

```
    heap size   method  duration (ms)
0         100   update       0.219107
1         100  heapify       0.412703
2         100     sort       0.242710
3        1000   update       0.198841
4        1000  heapify       2.947330
5        1000     sort       0.605345
6       10000   update       0.203848
7       10000  heapify      32.759190
8       10000     sort       4.621506
9      100000   update       0.348568
10     100000  heapify     327.646971
11     100000     sort      49.481153
12    1000000   update       0.256062
13    1000000  heapify    3475.244761
14    1000000     sort    1106.570005
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Dealing with private functions

> But _siftup and _siftdown are protected member in heapq, so they are not recommended to access from outside.

The code snippets are short, so you could just include them in your own code after renaming them as public functions:

```
def siftdown(heap, startpos, pos):
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Follow the path to the root, moving parents down until finding a place
    # newitem fits.
    while pos > startpos:
        parentpos = (pos - 1) >> 1
        parent = heap[parentpos]
        if newitem < parent:
            heap[pos] = parent
            pos = parentpos
            continue
        break
    heap[pos] = newitem

def siftup(heap, pos):
    endpos = len(heap)
    startpos = pos
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf.
    childpos = 2*pos + 1    # leftmost child position
    while childpos < endpos:
        # Set childpos to index of smaller child.
        rightpos = childpos + 1
        if rightpos < endpos and not heap[childpos] < heap[rightpos]:
            childpos = rightpos
        # Move the smaller child up.
        heap[pos] = heap[childpos]
        pos = childpos
        childpos = 2*pos + 1
    # The leaf at pos is empty now.  Put newitem there, and bubble it up
    # to its final resting place (by sifting its parents down).
    heap[pos] = newitem
    siftdown(heap, startpos, pos)
```

### Maintaining the heap invariant

> How to restore the heap invariant, when one element is out-of-order?

Using the high level heap API, you could make a series of count updates and then run heapify() before doing any more heap operations.   This might or might not be efficient enough for your needs.

That said, `heapify()` function is *very* fast.  Interestingly, the `list.sort` method is even more optimized and might beat `heapify()` for some types of inputs.

### Better data structure

> need to count the frequency of words, and maintain the top k max-count words, which prepare to output at any moment. So I use heap here. When one word count++, I need update it if it is in heap.

Consider using a different data structure than heaps.  At first, heaps seem well suited to the task, however finding an arbitrary entry in a heap is slow even though we can then update it quickly with siftup/siftdown.

Instead, consider keep a dictionary mapping from a word to a position in lists of words and counts.  Keeping those lists sorted requires only a position swap when a count is incremented:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

word2pos = {}
words = []    # ordered by descending frequency
counts = []   # negated to put most common first

def tally(word):
    if word not in word2pos:
        word2pos[word] = len(word2pos)
        counts.append(-1)
        words.append(word)
    else:
        pos = word2pos[word]
        count = counts[pos]
        swappos = bisect_left(counts, count, hi=pos)
        words[pos] = swapword = words[swappos]
        counts[pos] = counts[swappos]
        word2pos[swapword] = pos
        words[swappos] = word
        counts[swappos] = count - 1
        word2pos[word] = swappos

def topwords(n):
    return [(-counts[i], words[i]) for i in range(n)]
```

### Built in solution

There is a another "out-of-the-box" solution that might meet your need.  Just use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for word in 'one two one three two three three'.split():
...     c[word] += 1
...
>>> c.most_common(2)
[('three', 3), ('one', 2)]
```

## Binary tree or Sorted Container Solution

Another way to go is to use a binary tree or sorted container.  These have O(log n) insertion and removal.  And they stand ready to iterate in forward or reverse order without additional computation effort.

Here is a solution using Grant Jenk's wonderful [Sorted Containers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) package:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from itertools import islice

@dataclass(order=True, unsafe_hash=True, slots=True)
class Entry:
    count: int = field(hash=False)
    word: str

w2e = {}                  # type: Dict[str, Entry]
ss = SortedSet()          # type: Set[Entry]   

def tally(word):
    if word not in w2e:
        entry = w2e[word] = Entry(1, word)
        ss.add(entry)
    else:
        entry = w2e[word]
        ss.remove(entry)
        entry.count += 1
        ss.add(entry)

def topwords(n):
    return list(islice(reversed(ss), n)
```

Comment: If I do use that source code in software and make that available, do I understand Python's [license](https://docs.python.org/3/license.html#psf-license-agreement-for-python-release) correctly that I must include "a brief summary of the changes made to Python 3.10.4"? And would "I removed everything except these two functions" be a proper summary?

Comment: Swapping the link nodes is a bit complicated. Might be simpler to swap their contents instead. Or, even simpler, instead of a doubly linked list, just use a `list` and make the dict map to an index. Although all these methods are still slow if for example all words have count 1 and then we revisit them all from last to first, so that the while-loop has to move the last word over many previous words. Might be better to not store words individually as (word, count) pairs but store (wordset, count) pairs.

Comment: You're using `sortedcontainers` but you're linking to `sortedcollections` (interesting, I didn't even know the latter existed). The latter's `ValueSortedDict` sounds like it would be perfect for this.

Comment: Nice idea with `bisect`. Your `swapword` has the same count, right? So unless you want to explicitly do a complete swap, I think you don't need to do `counts[pos] = counts[swappos]` and you could do `counts[swappos] -= 1` to update the other one.