# Why is _siftup and _siftdown just the opposite in Python?

Tags: python, heap, heapq

From the definition of [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) in Wikipedia, 
`sift-up` is also called `up-heap` operation, and `sift-down` is called `down-heap`.

So in heap (complete binary tree), `up` means from leaf to root, and `down` means from root to leaf.

But in python, it seems just opposite. I'm confused by meaning of `siftup` and `siftdown`, and misused when my first time.

Here is the python version implementation of `_siftdown` and `_siftup` in `heapq`:

```
# 'heap' is a heap at all indices >= startpos, except possibly for pos.  pos
# is the index of a leaf with a possibly out-of-order value.  Restore the
# heap invariant.
def _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos):
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Follow the path to the root, moving parents down until finding a place
    # newitem fits.
    while pos > startpos:
        parentpos = (pos - 1) >> 1
        parent = heap[parentpos]
        if newitem < parent:
            heap[pos] = parent
            pos = parentpos
            continue
        break
    heap[pos] = newitem

def _siftup(heap, pos):
    endpos = len(heap)
    startpos = pos
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf.
    childpos = 2*pos + 1    # leftmost child position
    while childpos < endpos:
        # Set childpos to index of smaller child.
        rightpos = childpos + 1
        if rightpos < endpos and not heap[childpos] < heap[rightpos]:
            childpos = rightpos
        # Move the smaller child up.
        heap[pos] = heap[childpos]
        pos = childpos
        childpos = 2*pos + 1
    # The leaf at pos is empty now.  Put newitem there, and bubble it up
    # to its final resting place (by sifting its parents down).
    heap[pos] = newitem
    _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos)
```

Why opposite in python? I have confirmed in wiki and several other articles. Is there anything I missing or misunderstanding?

Thanks for reading, I really appreciate it to help me out. : )

Comment: You are not suppose to use either of those directly. They are internal to the heapq module as the underscore in their name denotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the references on the Wikipedia page, I spotted this:

> Note that this paper uses Floyd's original terminology "siftup" for what is now called sifting *down*.

It would seem that different authors have different references for what is "up" and "down".

But, as @Dan D writes in a comment, you are not supposed to be using those functions anyway.

Comment: thanks both of you @Dan D. I try to avoid use them either, and that is my another question, [how to avoid using _siftup and _siftdown when one element is out-of-order in heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373969/how-to-avoid-using-siftup-or-siftdown-in-heapq)